# Full calendar eventdisplay not respected when changing view

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Little question I have a FullCalendar v5 page linked to several google agendas. This part works well and default display is as **dayGridMonth** with eventDisplay as 'block'.

Based on window width, a changeView event is triggered to switch to **listMonth** if needed. This part works fine too.

However when switching to **listMonth**, eventdisplay does not respect the 'block' value. When reverting to **dayGridMonth**, it is correct

If implementing display property at event source level instead of globally, same behaviour.

Has someone an idea why ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional. The [documentation for eventDisplay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay) explicitly says that the `block` setting only applies to `daygrid` views:

> 'block' - When in daygrid, renders the event as a solid rectangle.
> When in other views, will render normally

Note the last sentence specifically.

Comment: OK, I missed that "daygrid" included "daygridmonth".

Isn't it inconsistent that event is rendered differently when calling changeView method ? After all it's all about to global overlay and not eventsources and their settings themselves.

Comment: Yes, daygrid is the type of view. daygridmonth is a daygrid view which specifically shows 1 month at a time. Just like you can have timegridday and timegridweek for example, both are timegrid views with a particular time range specified. As for consistency, yeah maybe it is inconsistent. You'd have to ask the makers of fullCalendar why they did it like that. But at least the documentation is clear about when it does and doesn't apply.

Comment: To compare what cannot be, V3 wasn't behaving this way.

Comment: Well, v3 didn't even have this option, so I'm not really sure what you're comparing it to exactly?

Comment: Indeed, not that option as such but when defining color and textcolor in events within eventsources, it was respecting this when dynamically changing view and reverting. With V5 not at all and having at least daygrid displayed as expected, eventDisplay has to be set to 'block'. Otherwise it use some "blue-ish"default color.

Comment: You're right it's different. This was documented in the change notes for v5: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4#event-rendering . If you don't like it, complain to the fullCalendar people - https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features.

Comment: P.S. the "list" view never displayed events in the block format in v3 anyway, so that bit hasn't changed, it wasn't consistent before either - month and agenda view was block style, list was non-block, just the dot and text.

Comment: "color" is still respected in the daygrid view with default settings as well - it just turns the dot red (as it has always done in the list view) rather than the whole thing.

Comment: You gave me an hint. I will fix display in list with CSS to remove that blue-ish background. At least it will be aligned with the rest.

Thx

Comment: The solid blue (not blue-ish IMO!) background is only for all-day and/or block-displayed events. In the default theme, non-block (and list view) events are black text with white background, and a blue dot. No blue anywhere. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/QWpvwmx . So I'm not really sure what you mean?

Comment: I have #3a87ad as color where you seem to have #3788d8. Tuning ".fc-list-table  tr.fc-list-event" elements using CSS with "background-color: transparent;" was more suitable with  my desired result. Your input was really helpful to find a workaround. Thx !

Comment: Maybe you had some other CSS in your page interfering with it. Glad you were able to solve it though.